# Как и где хранить параметры конкретного объекта?

Tags: c#, архитектура

Делаю программку, которая ищет устройства по сети.
По сети прилетает идентификатор устройства.

Устройств множество, характеристики их известны.

Например, есть модели устройств:
device1. Он имеет 4 порта, один датчик вскрытия, 2 кнопки.

device2: 3 порта, 2 датчика, 4 кнопки.

Как лучше хранить в такие устройства в программе?

1. Насоздавать экземпляров класса с заданными свойствами.
2. Десериализовывать из файла.
3. В Бд (бд будет присутствовать для других задач тоже).

По первому пункту тут скорее надо не экземпляр, а сам класс с дефолтными доступными только для чтения значениями свойств. Поскольку экземпляров может быть много. Свойства будут одинаковые, будут разные Ip адреса, как минимум.

Еще важно, чтоб можно легко добавлять в базу устройств новое, без пересбора программы. Поэтому похоже. Первый вараинт не очень.

Comment: "чтоб можно легко добавлять в базу устройств новое" - новый тип устройства со своим набором полей? Как будут использоваться специфические поля?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA да, имеется ввиду новый тип устройств, с иными значениями полей. Не совсем понял про специфические поля.

Comment: Какие данные для разных устройств должны храниться в программе? И как они будут использоваться? Или кроме типа устройства они ничем не отличаются?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA только те, что постоянные. Количество портов, датчиков и т.д. их достаточно  много. Остальные данные будут изменяемые - описание, местоположение и пр. Используются для отображения пользователю как результат сетевого поиска. А так же на каждую модель будет своя картинка, на которй будут показано соответствующее количество портов и их активность.

Comment: Т.е. в реультате поиска могут быть найдены 3 устройства. 2 из которых будут одного типа, с одинаковым количеством портов, датчиков и пр., но с разным описанием местоположения. Третье устройство будет иметь другое количество портов. Важно именно иметь конфиг, что такое-то устройство с таким то id имеет такой набор свойств. А еще скорее всего надо чтоб порты в будущем в экземпляре были списком. Т.е. если порта 4, то в списке 4 порта. Поскольку порт тоже будет иметь свойства.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел отличное решение для себя.
Использование паттерна прототип (в примере клонирование через сериализацию) + фабрика.
[Видео с Ютуба](https://youtu.be/Dk_ZqdLgLzY)

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Task<T> TryCreateDeepCopyAsync<T>(this T self)
    {
        if (self is null)
            return default;

        return self.TryCreateDeepCopyInternalAsync();
    }
    private static async Task<T> TryCreateDeepCopyInternalAsync<T>(this T self)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(stream, self);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(stream);                
        }
    }
}

class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Name: {Name}, Address: {Address}";
    }
}

class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string  City { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Street: {Street}, City: {City}";
    }
}

static class EmployeeFactory
{
    private static readonly Contact first = new Contact { Address = new Address { City = "Moskow", Street = "Lenina" } };
    private static readonly Contact second = new Contact { Address = new Address { City = "Moskow", Street = "Arbat" } };

    private static async Task<Contact> NewEmployeeAsync(string name, Contact prototype)
    {
        var result = await prototype.TryCreateDeepCopyAsync();
        result.Name = name;
        return result;
    }

    public static async Task<Contact> NewFirstEmployeeAsync(string name)
    {
        return await NewEmployeeAsync(name, first);
    }

    public static async Task<Contact> NewSecondEmployeeAsync(string name)
    {
        return await NewEmployeeAsync(name, second);
    }
}

public async Task Test()
{
    var person1 = await EmployeeFactory.NewFirstEmployeeAsync("Alex");
    var person2 = await EmployeeFactory.NewFirstEmployeeAsync("Fil");
    var person3 = await EmployeeFactory.NewSecondEmployeeAsync("Kate");
    var person4 = await EmployeeFactory.NewSecondEmployeeAsync("Rob");

    Debug.WriteLine(person1);
    Debug.WriteLine(person2);
    Debug.WriteLine(person3);
    Debug.WriteLine(person4);
}
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/754428)

Comment: @insolor, да, я планировал это сделать несколько позже, как время смогу выделить.

Comment: можно выкинуть `ExtensionMethods` и статические поля, и перенести вызов конструктора напрямую в функцию `public static Contact NewFirstEmployeeAsync(string name)
    {
        return new Contact { Address = new Address { City = "Moskow", Street = "Lenina" }, Name=name }
    }` код сократится в два раз и классы можно будет не отмечать атрибутом `serializable`

Comment: @Grundy В данном случае да.  У меня будет несколько сложнее. Там я подумаю. Тут некий общий случай. + ExtensionMethods позволит копировать что-то еще в будущем. У меня все равно эта постоянная часть должна будет браться либо из бд, либо изначально десериализовываться. Склоняюсь ко второму случаю. Например, как предлагаете вы, но не ручками прописывать Address , а десереализовать из файла

Comment: `JsonSerializer` не использует атрибут `Serializable`. Так что можно его удалить и проверки его наличия. | Этот атрибут используется при двоичной сериализации.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хм, проверю. Но исключение вроде бросилось. Хотя может когда бинарный был, затем я заменил.